# Display bug with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to make a Breadcrumb. So I made a service for this purpose.

I display all breadcrumbs using a `ng-repeat` in my HTML, and I am listening to the '$routeChangeStart' event to reset the breadcrumb and fill it with its new content.

The issue is: The breadcrumb is partially updated for a moment then fully updated.

Let me show you.

1. **Breadcrumb before '$routeChangeStart' event**

   Array content: `['Home', 'Product', 'Product Name']`

   Display on page: Home / Product / Product name
2. **'$routeChangeStart' event triggering**

   Array content: `[]`

   Display on page: `Home / Product / Product name`
3. **Page fully loaded**

   Array content: `['Home', 'New page']`

   Display on page: `/ Home / New page / Home / Product / Product page`
4. **Few miliseconds after**

   Display on page: `Home / New page`

So here's my question: What's happening here?

I already tried to tell angularjs the data changed by doing a 
`$scope.$apply`, or `$scope.$digest()` and `$timeout()` without success.

My breadcrumb is using a directive which render a .html template.

The directive:

```
app.directive('MenuTop', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/frontend/pages/menus/menu_top.html',
        controller: ['$scope', 'Breadcrumb', function($scope, Breadcrumb){
            $scope.Breadcrumb = Breadcrumb;
        }]
    };
});
```

Breadcrumb service: http://pastebin.com/GR8FTn3h

menu_top.html: http://pastebin.com/4j5m0PKA

Comment: And where’s your directive?

Comment: And can you show your Breadcrumb service?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @idmean, I will, sorry.
I updated my post will all needed infos

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your directive you assign value to

```
$scope.Breadcrumb = Breadcrumb
```

But it does not creates any watcher. You should do

```
$scope.$watch( 
   function() { return Breadcrumb; }, 
   function (newValue) { $scope.Breadcrumb = newValue}, 
   true
);
```

It will check Breadcrumb value on every digest cycle. 'true' in the  end means that you want deep-check, not reference check.

Scope docs: [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, it's not working as excepted

Comment: Do you call $apply inside your Breadcrumb factory? Because you create watcher inside of scope, but to make it work you have to start $digest to pickup change.

Comment: Do I have to do "$scope.apply()" or "$scope.applu(function(){implemention...})" inside my Breadcrumb factory ?

Comment: Well, I try $rootScope.$apply() and angular throws "digest already in progress", so I tried with $timeout(fn). Still the same display error.

Comment: Angular uses dirty checking mechanism to detect any changes inside your date. It means that on every $digest it runs functions which you send to $watch as first argument and compares result of this function with previous call, if it changed from last time angular runs second function from $watch arguments. So, in your case you have data inside your Breadcrumbs factory and when you change any data inside of it you have to be sure that $digest have started. You can use $rootScope.$$evalAsync to be sure that you will have no exceptions (Digest already in progress).

Comment: If you are profession front-end developer i recomend you read this book: http://teropa.info/build-your-own-angular .

Comment: I wrap the whole reset and add function into $evalAsync. Does not work either. It's kinda weird

Comment: It's like the template has a "cache" ng-repeat

Comment: So, I finaly resolved my issue. I don't know why but, I said it. It was a kinda "template caching". I put each single <li> element in a template called "breacrumb-item.html" and it sovles the issue. Thank you all for you answers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using $routeChangeEnd event and also replacing the array with new one instead of reusing the array instance ?